# Sending message from server to specific client is not working using SignalR 2 and MVC 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I wanted to call notify specific client from server using signalR but it was not working. my code was executed successfully but client dose not receive any call from server.

However this is working for all client.

```
var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProcessStatusNotifyHub>();
hubContext.Clients.All.notify("Got it!");
```

But this is not working for specific client
**[Updated Code]**
Following code written in chat.cshtml

```
$(function () {
       // Reference the auto-generated proxy for the hub.
       var chat = $.connection.processStatusNotifyHub;//chatHub;
       chat.client.notify = function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
       }
       // Start the connection.
       $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
           var myClientId = $.connection.hub.id;
           console.log('connected: ' + myClientId);
           $('#sendmessageToClient').click(function () {
                //chat.server.send('imdadhusen', 'This is test text');
                $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("Send", "PushNotification")',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: { 'clientID': myClientId },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (result) {
                            alert(result.status);
                 }
              });
           });
       });
});
```

Following code is written in Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Send(string clientID)
        {
             var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ProcessStatusNotifyHub>();
             //hubContext.Clients.All.notify("Got it!");
             hubContext.Clients.User(clientID).notify("Got it!");

             responseResult result = new responseResult();
             result.status = "OK";
             result.message = "Notification sent successfully";
             return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

I have tried debug the code it is showing correct value of client id on .cstml or controlloer. e.g. `clientid : 0fdf6cad-b9c1-409e-8eb7-0a57c1cfb3be`

Could you please help me to send notification to specific client from server.

Comment: Can you provide the full controller?  The code you have provided makes it unclear whether or not connectionId is in the correct scope for the operation you are trying to perform.

Comment: @Steve I have updated code for your reference, Please do let me know still you require more details for the same.

Comment: Thanks for updating.  When you debug the server, is the clientID set to the value you'd expect?

Comment: Actually client id is successfully passed to the controller and the statement was also executed without any error `hubContext.Clients.User(clientID).notify("Got it!");` but client side i am not getting message inside the function `chat.client.notify.`

Comment: If clientID is SignalR connection id I think you want `Clients.Client(clientID)` and not `Clients.User(clientID)`

Answer (score 2):

The operation `hubContext.Clients.User(string)` is expecting the User ID of the current HTTP request, not SignalR's client ID.

If you want to use client ID use this operation:

```
hubContext.Clients.Client(   )
```

If you want to access it by the current user, then you can get current user ID with this

```
string UserID=User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to your specific question, but instead a suggestion on your code.  Why not have the client use the Signalr connection to call the server?  Just define a method in the hub that a client can call.  Then in that method use the HubCallerContext to get the id.

This page shows you how to call the server from the client:
http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client

Then in the hub's method:

```
Clients.User(Context.ConnectionId).notify("Got it!");
```